# make html boxes "stick out"

Tags: html, css, block, margin

I am trying to make an "image strip" (a lot of small images floated to the left starting from left side of the screen to the right). The problem is when I resize the browser the images start "stacking" under (default block behaviour) instead of simply dissapearing , "sticking out of container". I've tried setting container's right margin to -9999px but it doesn't help.
 How can I achieve this ?

Edit: Here's the code:

```
<div id='headerImages'>
    <img class="headerImage" src="images/header/cakeshop/image001.png" />
    <img class="headerImage" src="images/header/cakeshop/image002.png" />
    <img class="headerImage" src="images/header/cakeshop/image003.png" />
    <img class="headerImage" src="images/header/cakeshop/image004.png" />
</div>
```

and css:

```
#headerImages {
    width: 60%;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-right: -9999px;
}

.headerImage {
    height: 300px;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: please post relevant code, i can tell you that this may work with `overflow: hidden` but it's hard to tell exactly what can be done with out seeing it.

Comment: Please provide of code, and a JSFiddle would help too.

Comment: I have the images loaded by php from a directory so I think it would be hard to recreate on JSFiddle , but the basic question is : is it possible to make images "stick out" of their div container using only css and html ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you need?

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/eZcza/6/)**

with your code:
html:

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id='headerImages'>
    <img class="headerImage" src="images/header/cakeshop/image001.png" />
    <img class="headerImage" src="images/header/cakeshop/image002.png" />
    <img class="headerImage" src="images/header/cakeshop/image003.png" />
    <img class="headerImage" src="images/header/cakeshop/image004.png" />
</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#wrapper {
    width: 60%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#headerImages{
    width:2000px; /* set the width to total width of your images */
}

.headerImage {
    height: 300px;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With out seeing it what you can do is set a `width` on your container as a percentage and set `overflow: hidden`. This will cause the images to be hidden inside the container rather than bump to the next line